# Update field with aggregate value

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update all rows of a parent table based on multiple child table records
I get the following error

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE p
SET p.QuantityOnHand =
    (ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty, 0)), 0) -
     ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(i.Qty, 0)), 0) -
     ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(s.Qty, 0)), 0))
FROM Products p

INNER JOIN BillDetails b ON p.ProductId = b.Pid
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails i ON p.ProductId = i.Pid
INNER JOIN SalesDetails s ON p.ProductId = s.Pid
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a group by but this still wouldn't work. 
My solution would be to first create a temp table where you store your result and than use the temp table for the update:

```
SELECT p.Pid, (ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty, 0)), 0) -
 ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(i.Qty, 0)), 0) -
 ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(s.Qty, 0)), 0)) AS Result
INTO #tmp
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN BillDetails b ON p.ProductId = b.Pid
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails i ON p.ProductId = i.Pid
INNER JOIN SalesDetails s ON p.ProductId = s.Pid
GROUP BY p.Pid


 UPDATE p
    SET p.QuantityOnHand = t.Result
   FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.Pid = p.Pid
```

Comment: Thanks @Bave i have tried it does the job . but the execution of the query takes very long  time,..for example when there is  2000 records in the parent table.. Any idea ...

Comment: @HaniMuhamed depends on where the performance issue is. During the creating of the temp table or during update? In each case, check the execution plan and create indexes if needed.

Comment: i thinks its during the update. The performance of the query deteriorates as the table gets bigger.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do about it except for adding faster storage. One option would be to create an Index on the temp table on Pid but I don't expect this to be the bottleneck.